# How can I prevent the Googlebot from indexing duplicate URLs?

Tags: seo, url, googlebot, duplicate-content

I have duplicate URLs for each ad page. For example:

`https://example.com/ads/2161/%D9%84%D9%83%D8%B2%D8%B3_GS350.html`

`https://example.com/2161/`

I used the second URL for Twitter and Instagram posts.

So I see a message in Google Webmaster Tools that there are duplicate title tags and content.

How can I fix this issue, I want the Googlebot to index only the first URL, not the second URL.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Just set canonical URL and it should fix it.

Example:

URL 1: http://www.example.com/product/first.html

URL 2: http://www.example.com/first.html

Let's say if you want google to crawl only URL 2 then in the first URL set URL 2 as canonical URL.

Code to go in the head section of URL 1:

```
<link rel=”canonical” href=”http://www.example.com/first.html” />
```

Comment: so if i want this url will be "https://example.com/ads/2161/%D9%84%D9%83%D8%B2%D8%B3_GS350.html" rel="canonical" , the other url will not crawl by google ! even it is on twitter .

Comment: @Esmail Yes. That's right.

Comment: i did that , but i tested it on google it is crawl the other link and not crawl what i want

Comment: If you setup canonical correctly and if you leave the setup for some time you should see the change. Also, you may like to share some URLs on social media like G+ and probably bot will come and visit the site again sooner and it should change the index. This is recommended approach and it should work.

Comment: i put rel="canonical" for url i want that google crawl it , unfortunately google crawl and index the other url , and i can't find the canonical on google search page !!

Comment: You can put in both and leave it for another week and see the impact. There are some other quick methods but may not fix it based on your need.